# Localdb display Chinese charaters as question mark

Tags: c#, localdb

For example I have a table with following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PrimaryCategory] 
(
    [Id]    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And I insert some data to the table

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    List<PrimaryCategory> categories = new List<PrimaryCategory>()
    {
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "政策理论" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "佛学讲记" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "佛学禅定" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "佛教心理学" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "人物介绍" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "幽默格言" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "文学" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "动态报道" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "介绍佛陀" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "介绍佛教" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "佛教故事" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "生活的教育" },
        new PrimaryCategory() { Title = "海内外佛教" }

    };
    ctx.PrimaryCategory.AddRange(categories);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
};
```

But it shows `???` in datagridview, and what if you change the data in datagridview, the `???` will again:

[image]

Comment: What character encoding does the DB use?

Comment: @Enigmativity: SQL Server uses UCS-2 for any `NVARCHAR` datatype columns (roughly equivalent to UTF-16 - normally 2 bytes per character).

Comment: @Enigmativity The instance collation for LocalDB is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and cannot be changed. Database-level, column-level, and expression-level collations are supported normally.

Comment: @TangMonk - And where is the code for `PrimaryCategoryForm` that shows how you are querying the database?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am using the datasource drag and drop

Comment: FYI The `[visual-studio]` tag is only intended for questions about the Visual Studio application.

Comment: @TangMonk - There's still code when you use a datasource. Can you show it?

Comment: One typeface (font) are you using on the Grid View? (Not all include a full set of Han characters... and fallback might not be finding the right glyphs).

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your encoding in DB. If in DB property Title = ???, then change encoding in db use

```
ALTER DATABASE [YOURDATABASE] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

2) if in DB shows normal Title, then change encoding, when you get PrimaryCategory class to Unicode using Encoding.Convert

Comment: The Collate is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` by default

Comment: try collate **Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AI** or **Chinese_Simplified_Stroke_Order_100_CI_AI**.
If this dosn't help, try encode to unicode before save in DB

Answer (score 0):

Using following sql to change the collate:

```
alter database "C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\Database.mdf" set single_user with rollback immediate ; 
go

alter database "C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\Database.mdf" collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AS ; 
go

alter database "C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\Database.mdf" set multi_user;
```

[image]

But why Visual Studio do not privde a selection dropdown to arvhice this？